# How to create table with only check boxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for a Windows Forms Control that looks like a grid of a check boxes in C#. Something like this I guess, hope it makes sense.

[image]

So how would I go about making this happen, is it even possible?

Comment: you can make your own using tablelayoutpanel and checkboxes

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TableLayoutPanel`, this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tablelayoutpanel) may help you to know some of its properties, and this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/tablelayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/) is example for using it

Answer (score 1):

Strongly avoid a TableLayoutPanel it is *much* too expensive with this many check boxes.

DataGridView is the appropriate choice, change the column types to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.  Editing only requires a single real checkbox control, taken care of automatically.  No problems with focus either.

Making your own is a very reasonable approach as well, you can make it look any way you want.  Derive a class from Control, Panel if you need it to be scrollable.  ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox() can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to render the check boxes.

This sample creates a `TableLayoutPanel` by code:

```
TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();

int rowCount = 2;
int columnCount = 2;

for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(checkBox, column, row);
    }
}

this.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
```